# Firestore multiple compound indexes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a filter component that can filter based on multiple fields. All of the fields are using the equality operator, and I have sorting based on "created" field.
Something along the lines of

```
let queryBuilder = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('myCollection')
    .doc(docId)
    .collection('myInnerCollection')
    .orderBy('created', 'desc');

const {field1, field2, field3} = filter;
if (field1) {
    queryBuilder = queryBuilder.where('field1', '==', field1);
}
if (field2) {
    queryBuilder = queryBuilder.where('field2', '==', field2);
}
if (field3) {
    queryBuilder = queryBuilder.where('field3', '==', field3);
}
```

For every field I'm required to create a compound index with 'created' field. i.e:

```
index field1(+) created(-)  
index field2(+) created(-)  
index field3(+) created(-)
```

Once I do that, every combination of filtering works. So my question is, if I know that field1 is always populated should I create just two compounded indexes:

```
index field1(+) field2(+) created(-)  
index field1(+) field3(+) created(-)
```

Or having the 3 indexes is also ok?
Is there any performance/storage penalty of using each one? if so, what is the penalty (assuming I have 100K records in my collection)?